# Show that if $\lim_{n \to +\infty} $($x_n)$ = $L$ for $L$ ∈ R then $f(L)$=$L$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continuity

I struggle to fully prove the following:

If  $f:\mathbb{R}$→$\mathbb{R}$ is continuous for any $x\in \mathbb{R}$,  consider the sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ with $x_1 = a$  and $x_n=f(x_{n-1})$ for $n>2$.
**If $x_n$ converges to $L$ then prove that $f(L)=L$.**

***My approach is :***

I know that since $f$ is continuous then $\lim_{n \to +\infty} f(x_n)$= $f\left(\lim_{n \to +\infty} (x_n)\right)$.
I need somehow to show that if $\lim_{n \to +\infty}x_n = L$ then $f(L)=L$.

Let $\{x_n\}$ be a convergent sequence  with limit $L$, and let $f$ be a continuous function.

Then $\{f(x_n)\}$ is a convergent sequence with limit $f(L)$.

**Question:**
Which theorem/definition can I use to prove it?

Comment: You need to edit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Since $x_n\to L$, we have $x_{n-1}\to L$
- Therefore $f(x_{n-1})\to f(L)$
- We got $$\begin{array}{ccc}x_n&=&f(x_{n-1})\\ \downarrow &&\downarrow \\ L &&f(L)\end{array}.$$
- Therefore $L=f(L)$.